# Shortest path algorithm BFS--Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I'm working on the following algorithm problem:

```
You are given a m x n 2D grid initialized with these three possible values.

-1 - A wall or an obstacle.
0 - A gate.
INF - Infinity means an empty room. We use the value 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647 to represent INF as you may assume that the distance to a gate is less than 2147483647.
Fill each empty room with the distance to its nearest gate. If it is impossible to reach a gate, it should be filled with INF.

For example, given the 2D grid:
INF  -1  0  INF
INF INF INF  -1
INF  -1 INF  -1
  0  -1 INF INF
After running your function, the 2D grid should be:
  3  -1   0   1
  2   2   1  -1
  1  -1   2  -1
  0  -1   3   4
```

This is an obvious BFS problem-- and I (and the provided solution) both attempted to solve by launching a BFS from each gate at the same time. The problem requests returning a matrix in place, so I do that as well in the program below. Here's my question: with the test case in the problem description above, here's my solution:

```
[[ 3,-1, 0, 1],
 [ 2, 2, 1,-1],
 [ 1,-1, 2,-1],
 [ 0,-1, 2, 1]]
```

As you can see, my solution is really close except for the last two numbers in the matrix. My solution outputs 2, 1 and the correct solution is 3,4.
I'm having trouble figuring out why this is. Because I adjust the matrix in place and skip over any cells that aren't empty, those last two cells shouldn't be affected by any adjustments made previously. Since they're being updated, it clearly isn't an issue of some out-of-bounds error.

Does anyone see anything wrong with my code?

```
#BFS from each gate-- any room that isn't touched is left as INF
GATE = 0
EMPTY = 2147483647
BLOCKED = -1
DIRECTIONS = [[1,0],[-1,0],[0,1],[0,-1]]
def walls_and_gates(rooms)
    queue = Queue.new
    m = rooms.length - 1
    n = rooms.first.length - 1
    0.upto(m) do |row|
        0.upto(n) do |col|
            if rooms[row][col] == GATE #enqueues all gates for BFS
                queue.enq([row,col])
            end
        end
    end
    traverse(rooms, queue, m, n)
end

def traverse(rooms, queue, m, n)
    until queue.empty?
        current = queue.deq
        row, col = current
        adj_positions = adj_points(current, m, n, rooms)
        adj_positions.each do |adj|
            r, c = adj
            rooms[r][c] = rooms[row][col] + 1 #marks distance from current gate/room.
            queue.enq(adj)
        end
    end
end

private
def adj_points(pos, m, n, rooms) #only returns empty adjacent rooms to be traversed
    valid_points = []
    row, col = pos
    DIRECTIONS.each do |dir|
        r_delta, c_delta = dir

        if (row + r_delta > m) || (col + c_delta > n) || (row + r_delta < 0) || (row + c_delta < 0) || rooms[row + r_delta][col + c_delta] != EMPTY #this checks if the room is empty. if not empty, it has been visited or its blocked by a wall, etc. 
            next
        else
            valid_points << [row + r_delta, col + c_delta]
        end
    end
    valid_points
end
```

Comment: I don't see any logical error, however i recommend printing the whole matrix after each dequeue operation. This will help in narrowing the part causing the error.